# Unit testing exception property

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have exception

```
class SyntaxError : Exception {
    public SyntaxError(int l) {
        line = l;
    }
    public int line;
}
```

I'm using unit tests to test class Parser which on specific input should throw exception above. I'm using code like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Parser.SyntaxError))]
    public void eolSyntaxError()
    {
        parser.reader = new StringReader("; alfa\n; beta\n\n\n\na");
        parser.eol();
    }
```

Is there any smart simple way to check if `SyntaxError.line == 1`?

Best I come up with is:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void eolSyntaxError()
    {
        try {
            parser.reader = new StringReader("; alfa\n; beta\n\n\n\na");
            parser.eol();
            Assert.Fail();
        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, e.line);
        }
    }
```

I don't like it very much, is there better way?

Comment: What do you don't like about it?

Comment: It's just seems there must be simpler way, it looks like too much code for such a simple thing.. But if it's the best way I'll do it like it

Comment: If the state of the line value is relevant at the time of throwing the exception, then include it as a parameter on the exception.

Comment: @Matt How would I do that? I'm not exactly C# guru..

Comment: Side note, classes that inherit from `System.Exception` should end in the suffix `Exception`, thus it should be `SyntaxException` according to [Microsoft's naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It is arguably messier still, but you could embed the line number into the exception message and then test the message using the message parameter of ExpectedExceptionAttribute.

Comment: @KeithPayne that's a nice hack :) this is small school project, so I'm not really worrier about style as I am about amount of code needed to be writen.. so this is actually exactly what I needed. adding `public override ToString() { return line.ToString() }` to my exception class and then using just `[ExpectedException(typeof(Parser.SyntaxError), "1")]` is genius solution. Can you write your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Posted below with a bit more detail.

Comment: As was pointed out in a comment to my posted answer (which will be deleted shortly), I am completely wrong about the second parameter of ExpectedException. This will not work for unit testing - although you can still inherit ApplicationException and use a descriptive error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions). Your test will then look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void eolSyntaxError()
{
    parser.reader = new StringReader("; alfa\n; beta\n\n\n\na");

    Action parseEol = () => parser.eol();

    parseEol
        .ShouldThrow<SyntaxError>()
        .And.line.Should().Be(1);
}
```

Otherwise, your approach is pretty much as good as it gets.

Comment: thanks for tip, if I needed something more complex this would look great, but for my (limited) use case it's to much code, my try/catch is maybe shorter.. + one of the comment suggested better solution (for my needs)

Comment: @Paladin: no problem. I would advise *against* rolling your own assertions logic (as other answers might suggest); either stick with `try-catch` (it your case it might be good enough) or use 3rd party libraries (like FluentAssertions) -- don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a method similar to the one in NUnit

```
public T Throws<T>(Action code) where T : Exception
{
    Exception coughtException = null;
    try
    {
        code();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        coughtException = ex;
    }

    Assert.IsNotNull(coughtException, "Test code didn't throw exception");
    Assert.AreEqual(coughtException.GetType(), typeof(T), "Test code didn't throw same type exception");

    return (T)coughtException;
}
```

And then you can use it in your test method

```
Parser.SyntaxError exception = Throws<Parser.SyntaxError>(() => parser.eol());
Assert.AreEqual(1, exception.line);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, if the line at which you encounter the syntax error is relevant, then include it in your custom exception class, like so.

```
public class SyntaxError : Exception
{
     public SyntaxError(int atLine)
     {
         AtLine = atLine;
     }

     public int AtLine { get; private set; }
}
```

Then it's easy to test.

EDIT - After having read the question (!) here's a simple additional Assert method which will tidy up your exception assertions.

```
public static class xAssert
{
    public static TException Throws<TException>(Action a) where TException : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            a();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var throws = ex as TException;
            if (throws != null)
                return throws;
        }
        Assert.Fail();
        return default(TException);
    }
}
```

Usage as follows...

```
public class Subject
{
    public void ThrowMyException(int someState)
    {
        throw new MyException(someState);
    }

    public void ThrowSomeOtherException()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

public class MyException : Exception
{
    public int SomeState { get; private set; }

    public MyException(int someState)
    {
        SomeState = someState;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var subject = new Subject();
        var exceptionThrown = xAssert.Throws<MyException>(() => { subject.ThrowMyException(123); });

        Assert.AreEqual(123, exceptionThrown.SomeState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Matt, what's your solution to the problem?

Comment: I can definitely do that, I already have `public int line`... but how will it help me test it?

Comment: Oh damn. Sorry. One of these days I'm going to learn to read. Ignore me.

Comment: There is a nice extension for NUnit which combines both an assertion and and assignment at the same time, something like Assert.Throws<TException>(Action). Wouldn't be hard to roll your own which does this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an out of the box solution for this, but I have seen the concept of expectations which work like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EolSyntaxError()
{
    Expectations.Expect<(SyntaxError>(
        () =>
        {
            parser.reader = new StringReader("; alfa\n; beta\n\n\n\na");
            parser.eol();
        },
        e =>
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, e.line);
        });
}
```

Expectations needs to be implemented. I reckon there will be libraries out there which already do this. Anyhow, the `Expect` method in `Expectations` could look like this:

```
public static void Expect<TExpectedException>(
    System.Action action,
    System.Action<TExpectedException> assertion) where TExpectedException : Exception
{
    if (action == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("action"); }
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
        Assert.Fail(string.Format("{0} expected to be thrown", typeof(TExpectedException).Name));
    }
    catch (TExpectedException e)
    {
        assertion.Invoke(e);
    }
}
```